# Recurrence relation with geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Reading the seemingly excellent book Basic Stochastic Processes (Brzezniak), but got confused by a derivation, page 86-87 specifically. We arrive at this formula:

$x_{n+1} - \frac{q}{p+q} = (1-p-q)(x_n - \frac{q}{p+q})$

on the next row, it says "Thus, $\{x_n-\frac{q}{p+q}\}$ is a geometric sequence and therefore, for all $n \in \textbf{N}$, $x_n-\frac{q}{p+q} = (1-p-q)^n(x_0 -\frac{q}{p+q})$."

How do we arrive at that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh what they in fact did was to define $y_n = x_n - \frac{q}{p+q}$ then the recurrence relation becomes $y_{n+1} = (1-p-q) y_n$. Solve that for $y_n$ and substitute $y_n = x_n - \frac{q}{p+q}$ after that, then you'll get that answer.